# I am looking for someone that has patience to help me understand VB terminology and the hows and whys

Tags: vb.net

Some basic terms that interchange that i have no one to ask, and i guess to stupid to understand my self.
Method,procedure, parameters, operation, operator, function, instaniantiantion, separator,
I really need help!
I really need to see a long module of code that every thing is broken down for a stupid guy like me.

For instance break this down, not what it does but how it does it, and the terminology. Word by word,, all dots, = parentheses, the passes the gets all that stuff, I know that this is simple to everyone else. And i will need more help until i get it... Maybe we can work something out. Some one that is available,,, that knows this stuff backwards and forwards and has the patience, that would like to help me... I have tried books   i just do not get it  HELP

```
Public Class ViewerForm1

    Private Sub btnSelectPicture_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectPicture.Click
        'Show the open dialog box.
        If ofdSelectPicture.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            'Load the picture in the box.
            btnSelectPicturePicture.Image = Image.FromFile(ofdSelectPicture.FileName)
            'Show the name of the file in the forms caption.
            Me.Text = "Picture Viewer "(ofdSelectPicture.FileName)
            'Close the window at exit the application.
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: It takes quite a while to understand programming. I recommend continuing your studies and come back here once you have some specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub btnSelectPicture_Click(sender As Object,
                                   e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectPicture.Click
```

This line declares a default Click event handler and binds button's click event to it.

```
If ofdSelectPicture.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
```

Opens an open file dialog and if user presses OK, processes the result.

```
btnSelectPicturePicture.Image = Image.FromFile(ofdSelectPicture.FileName)
```

Loads the image into the button, based on the file previously selected.

```
Me.Text = "Picture Viewer "(ofdSelectPicture.FileName)
```

Line does not make sense and probably won't compile. Missing a `&` or a `+` for string concatenation. Assuming it had one, it would assign a form caption/title to a constant value + a file name that was selected.

```
Me.Close()
```

Closes the current form.